# why are my firebase storage files 0 bytes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[Google Firebase Storage Image (for Reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2KdE.png)
I am trying to save photos taken from a camera intent and save them to Firebase Storage. Because I am targeting Android API 25, I must use a Fileprovider to create the URI for the image. 
I am able to successfully open the camera, take a photo, and upload the photo to my Firebase Storage bucket. The file is uploaded to Firebase and it is named correctly (as specified in my code). However, I receive the error "Error Loading Preview" and the file size is 0 bytes. When I download the file on my computer (a jpeg) the windows gallery says "We can't open this file"

Has anyone else run into this problem?

```
public class AddPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_GALLERY_PICKER = 321;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 123;

private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private StorageReference mStorage;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "co.mymemento.mementocaregiver.fileprovider", photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("memento_images").child(photoUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(photoUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding logging in your success and failure listeners?  Seems like those would give you some information about what happened.

Comment: I have not but I will try. On the bright side, I have it successfully uploading images from the Gallery. I am trying to apply the same logic for a camera intent now, I will see if I can get that to work.

Comment: There's a piece missing: the code in `onActivityResult()`.  If you have it, please post it.  If not, that's the problem.  You need something [like this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) except you get the `Uri` for the full image instead of the data for the thumbnail.

Comment: I have an onActivityResult that (attempts) to handle both the Gallery Result (which is working) and the Camera Result (which is not working)

Comment: I will add that code to the question

Comment: just before uploading the image Log the size of your uri/ inputstream whichever you are using, in most of the cases the uri is empty or inputream is empty brfore uploading it so the size becomes zero in database